# Can I mark an iterator as finished prematurely?

Tags: python

Is there an idiomatic way to finish an iterator early, so that any further next()s raise StopIteration?  (I can think of ugly ways, like abusing itertools.takewhile or discarding values until the thing is exhausted).

*Edit*:

My algorithm takes n iterators of unknown variable length as input.  It uses izip_longest() to read one item from each in n-tuples, until all are exhausted. Sometimes I find that I want to stop input early from one of the iterators according to some runtime criterion, and replace it with the stream of default values provided by izip_longest().  The least invasive way I can think of is to 'finish' it somehow.

Comment: Please show us the use case you're after. In theory, this should be possible, but I can't really say much until I know what you're trying to do

Comment: this sounds like a bad idea in general ... there is almost certainly  a better way to accomplish the behaviour you want

Comment: It looks like not wanting to `break` in a `for` loop and it doesn't looks good from here with no examples :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`itertools` Recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

> ```
> def consume(iterator, n):
>     "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
>     # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
>     if n is None:
>         # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
>         collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
>     else:
>         # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
>         next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
> ```

Comment: a little bit time consuming for infinite iterators.

Comment: Slower than necessary in the finite case also, but good enough for my needs.  And if it's in the itertools docs, I guess it must be 'pythonic'.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyIter:
    def __init__(self,what):
       self.what = what
       self.done = False
       self.iter = iter(what)
    def __iter__(self):
       self.done = False
       self.iter = iter(self.what)
    def next(self):
       if self.done: raise StopIteration
       return next(self.iter)

x = MyIter(range(100))
print next(x)
x.done=True
next(x)
```

but this sounds like a bad idea in general

what you should really do is

```
for my_iterator in all_iterators:
    for element in my_iterator: #iterate over it 
       if check(element): #if whatever condition is true
           break #then we are done with this iterator on to the next
```

for the example listed in the comments by @jme use something like this

```
for i,my_iterator in enumerate(all_iterators):
    for j,element in enumerate(my_iterator): #iterate over it 
       if j > i: #if whatever condition is true
           break #then we are done with this iterator on to the next
       else:
           do_something(element)
```

Comment: In light of the OP's edit in which he gives his use case, does this become a good idea? What's the preferred way of doing what he'd like?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your edit produces all elements from one iterator before moving to the next, when the OP wanted the first element each iterator, then the second from each, and so on...

Comment: no `break` terminates ... and just discards the iterator and moves on ... so whenever check returns true its done

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear... I agree that the break will discard the iterator and continue with the next, but the OP wants to zip the iterators, not chain them: `(a[0], b[0]), (a[1], b[1]), <deactivate a>, (<filled value>, b[2]), ...` instead of `a[0], a[1], <deactivate a>, b[0], b[1], b[2], ...`.

Comment: oh I see now ... yeah my bad ... I guess he can terminate it ... I still feel like thats not a good way to do it... but not sure how else...

Answer (score 1):

In your edit, you give your use-case: you want something that behaves like `izip_longest`, but allows you to "disable" iterators prematurely. Here's an iterator class that allows this, as well as "enabling" a previously-disabled iterator.

```
class TerminableZipper(object):

    def __init__(self, iterators, fill="n/a"):
        self.iterators = collections.OrderedDict((it, True) 
                                                 for it in iterators)
        self.fill = fill
        self.zipper = itertools.izip_longest(*iterators, fillvalue=fill)

    def disable(self, iterator):
        self.iterators[iterator] = False
        self._make_iterators()

    def enable(self, iterator):
        self.iterators[iterator] = True
        self._make_iterators()

    def _make_iterators(self):
        def effective(it):
            iterator, active = it
            return iterator if active else iter([])

        effective_iterators = map(effective, self.iterators.items())                
        self.zipper = itertools.izip_longest(*effective_iterators, 
                                             fillvalue=self.fill)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return next(self.zipper)
```

An example:

```
>>> it_a = itertools.repeat(0)
>>> it_b = iter(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])
>>> it_c = iter(["q", "r", "x"])
>>> zipper = TerminableZipper([it_a, it_b, it_c])
>>> next(zipper)
(0, 'a', 'q')
>>> next(zipper)
(0, 'b', 'r')
>>> zipper.disable(it_a)
>>> next(zipper)
('n/a', 'c', 'x')
>>> zipper.enable(it_a)
>>> next(zipper)
(0, 'd', 'n/a')
```

Comment: ok now that I understand better what OP wanted ... way to read between the lines :P

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer, which I've decided to post separately because it's of a different flavor than my other one. I think this might be preferable: keep the iterators in an ordered dict mapping each iterator to `{True, False}` (`True` if the iterator is active, `False` otherwise). First we want a function that takes such a dict and calls `next` on each iterator, returning the default value and updating an iterator's status if it is exhausted:

```
import itertools
import collections

def deactivating_zipper(iterators, default):
    while True:
        values = []
        for iterator, active in iterators.items():
            if active:
                try:
                    values.append(next(iterator))
                except StopIteration:
                    values.append(default)
                    iterators[iterator] = False
            else:
                values.append(default)

        if not any(iterators.values()):
            return
        else:  
            yield values
```

So now if we have three iterators:

```
it_a = iter(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
it_b = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
it_c = iter(["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"])

iterators = collections.OrderedDict((it, True) for it in (it_a, it_b, it_c))
```

We can just loop over them thusly:

```
for a,b,c in deactivating_zipper(iterators, "n/a"):

    # deactivate it_a
    if b == 3:
        iterators[it_a] = False

    print a,b,c
```

This gives output:

```
a 1 foo
b 2 bar
c 3 baz
n/a 4 quux
n/a 5 n/a
n/a 6 n/a
n/a 7 n/a
n/a 8 n/a
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer in one important sense - it's constant time as opposed to linear in the length of the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I opted for abusing `itertools.takewhile()` after all.  It's a bit more succinct than the other answers which use flags to 'consume' the iterator in constant time:

```
from itertools import takewhile, izip_longest

def f(seqs):
    done = [False] * len(seqs)
    iters = [ takewhile(lambda _, i=i: not done[i], s) for i, s in enumerate(seqs) ]
    zipped = izip_longest(*iters)

    # for example:
    print next(zipped)
    done[1] = True
    print next(zipped)
    print next(zipped)

f((['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']))
```

Output:

```
('a', 1, 'foo')
('b', None, 'bar')
('c', None, 'baz')
```